# VBA Excel, filter Date variable

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel Need to replace the Date as a Variable :-

```
'Working with Date :-
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$1706").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "01-feb-2023")


'Working with Variable :-
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$1706").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, """ & Main_Date & """)
```

Getting and Error, while working with Variable :-
Run-time error '1004':
AutoFilter method of Range Class Failed

In Excel Need to replace the Date as a Variable :-

```
'Working with Date :-
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$1706").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, "01-feb-2023")


'Working with Variable :-
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$1706").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, """ & Main_Date & """)
```

Getting and Error, while working with Variable :-
Run-time error '1004':
AutoFilter method of Range Class Failed

Comment: What's the type and value of 'Main_Date' variable? Make sure it is properly defined and formatted. It should be a string containing a date in the format "dd-mmm-yyyy".

Comment: Convert the date to a long value: `Criteria2:=Array(2, clng(Main_Date))` if you are not an on english system.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the use of extra quotes around the concatenation of Main_Date. The triple quotes """ are causing a syntax error, leading to the runtime error '1004'.

The corrected syntax removes the unnecessary quotes and directly uses the variable:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$1706").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, Main_Date)
```

Comment: In this case the  filtering on Date is not working , Date is coming Blank

Comment: Can you provide more information about 'Main_Date' variable? It could be an issue with date format compatibility. You should verify that the date format in 'Main_Date' matches the date format in the the excel sheet.